# When do we need to call java.sql.Connection.rollback()?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have to modify a few tables in one function. They must all succeed, or all fail. If one operation fails, I want them all to fail. I have the following:

```
public void foo() throws Exception {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = ...;
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        grok(conn);
        conn.commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // do I need to call conn.rollback() here?
    }
    finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
            conn = null;
        }
    }
}

private void grok(Connection conn) throws Exception {
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    try {
        // modify table "apple" 
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(...);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        stmt.close();

        // modify table "orange"
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(...);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        stmt.close();

        ...
    }
    finally {
        if (stmt != null) {
            stmt.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if I need to call rollback() in the case that something goes wrong during this process.

Other info: I'm using connection pooling. In the sample above, I'm also making sure to close each PreparedStatement using finally statements as well, just left out for brevity.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `rollback()`. If the connection closes without completing `commit()` it will be rolled back.

You don't need to set `conn` to `null` either; and since the `try` block starts after `conn` is initialized (assuming `...` cannot evaluate to null) you don't need the `!= null` in `finally` either.

Comment: Ok updated the example to reflect that conn may be null, so even with the updates I still don't need to call rollback()? Thanks

Comment: Correct, you don't need to call rollback. Your previous example, where `conn` was initialized before `try` was better

Comment: This is simply not true. You MUST call rollback on the connection for your changes to rollback. They will not be automatically rolled back for you. See my answer but its easy to test for yourself by throwing an exception before calling commit.

Comment: Hi @UsmanMutawakil so what would happen if you neither `commit` nor `rollback`?

Comment: @MiserableVariable Hello. If you neither commit nor rollback your inserts will be persisted but whether or not they can be read will depend upon the Transaction isolation level that your using. In my case, I could see the data "dirty read". The driver and database your using set transaction isolation levels but by explicitly rollingback half of the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need to call rollback if any of your statements fails or you have detected an exception prior to calling commit. This is an old post but the accepted answer is wrong. You can try it for yourself by throwing an exception before commit and observing that your inserts still make it into the database if you do not manually rollback.

**JDBC Documentation**
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html#call_rollback

**Example Correct Usage from the doc**

> ```
> public void updateCoffeeSales(HashMap<String, Integer> salesForWeek)
>     throws SQLException {
>
>     PreparedStatement updateSales = null;
>     PreparedStatement updateTotal = null;
>
>     String updateString =
>         "update " + dbName + ".COFFEES " +
>         "set SALES = ? where COF_NAME = ?";
>
>     String updateStatement =
>         "update " + dbName + ".COFFEES " +
>         "set TOTAL = TOTAL + ? " +
>         "where COF_NAME = ?";
>
>     try {
>         con.setAutoCommit(false);
>         updateSales = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
>         updateTotal = con.prepareStatement(updateStatement);
>
>         for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : salesForWeek.entrySet()) {
>             updateSales.setInt(1, e.getValue().intValue());
>             updateSales.setString(2, e.getKey());
>             updateSales.executeUpdate();
>             updateTotal.setInt(1, e.getValue().intValue());
>             updateTotal.setString(2, e.getKey());
>             updateTotal.executeUpdate();
>             con.commit();
>         }
>     } catch (SQLException e ) {
>         JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
>         if (con != null) {
>             try {
>                 System.err.print("Transaction is being rolled back");
>                 con.rollback();
>             } catch(SQLException excep) {
>                 JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(excep);
>             }
>         }
>     } finally {
>         if (updateSales != null) {
>             updateSales.close();
>         }
>         if (updateTotal != null) {
>             updateTotal.close();
>         }
>         con.setAutoCommit(true);
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you call "commit" then the transaction will be committed. If you have multiple insert/update statements and one of them fails, committing will cause the inserts/updates that didn't fail to commit to the database. So yes, if you don't want the other statements to commit to the db, you need to call rollback. What you are essentially doing by setting autocommit to false is allowing multiple statements to be committed or rolledback together. Otherwise each individual statement will automatically commit.

Comment: To clarify my answer, this assumes that you will have multiple statements. In your example where you only have one statement then it will be rolled back automatically. But if you have multiple statements being called in your Java code then you'd want to rollback.

Comment: I updated to show that there are multiple statements (well the variable is reused) - do I still need the rollback? Thanks

Comment: You should code defensively. The above code will work with a single connection and you don't need to explicitly call rollback. But if you were to drop that code into an environment where you have connection pools, you are bound to get strange behavior as other transactions reuse that same connection because connections are frequently never closed in a pool. Personally I would always use rollback unless you can definitely identify it as causing a performance hit (rollbacks are expensive) and you fully understand the transactional behavior of the environment you are working in.